# C++: undefined reference to the functor's overloaded invocation operator

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

```
template <typename T>
class Predicate {
   public:
    bool operator()(const T& x) const;
};

template <typename T>
class LessThan : public Predicate<T> {
   public:
    explicit LessThan(const T& v) : val(v) {}
    bool operator()(const T& x) const { return x < val; }

   private:
    const T val;
};

template <typename C, typename T>
class Producer {
   public:
    T operator()(const C& c) const;
};

template <typename C, typename V>
class HowMuch : public Producer<C, int> {
   public:
    explicit HowMuch(Predicate<V> p) : predicate{p} {}
    int operator()(const C& c) const {
        int count = 0;
        for (const auto& x : c)
            if (predicate(x)) ++count;
        return count;
    }

   private:
    Predicate<V> predicate;
};

int main() {
    const LessThan<int> lf(5);
    const HowMuch<list<int>, int> hm(lf);
    list<int> li {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    cout << "How much numbers less than 5 is in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "
            "10}? Answer: "
         << hm(li)
         << endl;
}
```

When compiling the aforementioned code g++ prints this to the console:

> /tmp/ccblK6El.o: In function `HowMuch<std::__cxx11::list<int,`
>   `std::allocator<int> >, int>::operator()(std::__cxx11::list<int,`
>   `std::allocator<int> > const&) const`:
>   templates.cpp:(.text._ZNK7HowMuchINSt7__cxx114listIiSaIiEEEiEclERKS3_[_ZNK7HowMuchINSt7__cxx114listIiSaIiEEEiEclERKS3_]+0x84):
>   undefined reference to `Predicate<int>::operator()(int const&) const`
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status The terminal process
>   terminated with exit code: 1

I can't quite get what is the problem with `Prediate<V>` definition inside `HowMuch`, because for me (a newbie in C++) it really looks LGTM. From my understanding the compiler creates a definition of `Predicate<int>` as a separate type, and the logs say exactly that, but for some reason it can't find the typed definition of the overloaded invocation operator. May be the problem is with the type deduction? Template of a container template type itself has to be somehow explicitly defined?

EDIT:

`virtual` modifier was added to both `Predicate`'s and `Producer`'s function operator overloads, but the problem, as it seems, persists. The error "description" (if it can be called as helpful description) is changed a bit, however (but still it points to the same problem):

> /tmp/ccn1Swqa.o: In function HowMuch >, int>::operator()(std::__cxx11::list > const&) const:
>   templates.cpp:(.text._ZNK7HowMuchINSt7__cxx114listIiSaIiEEEiEclERKS3_[_ZNK7HowMuchINSt7__cxx114listIiSaIiEEEiEclERKS3_]+0x76):
>   undefined reference to Predicate::operator()(int const&) const
>   /tmp/ccn1Swqa.o:(.rodata._ZTV8ProducerINSt7__cxx114listIiSaIiEEEiE[_ZTV8ProducerINSt7__cxx114listIiSaIiEEEiE]+0x10):
>   undefined reference to Producer >, int>::operator()(std::__cxx11::list > const&) const
>   /tmp/ccn1Swqa.o:(.rodata._ZTV9PredicateIiE[_ZTV9PredicateIiE]+0x10):
>   undefined reference to Predicate::operator()(int const&) const
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status The terminal process
>   terminated with exit code: 1

Comment: It seems you want C++20 concepts, instead of this unneeded inheritance.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm learning C++ as a support language, not more, so jumping from Stroustrup's C++11 book straight to c++20 standard seems inadequate, especially when the problem is already resolved

Comment: Which is the purpose of `Predicate`? Seems unneeded. Indeed current answer fix compilation issue, but base class seems useless here.

Comment: @Jarod42 this code obviously serves no purpose aside of practicing of features that I'm getting from the book, whereas here I just wanted to create a Java 8 port of functional interfaces hierarchy to see if it works as expected. And how does it relate to the original question at all? I won't stop you from making this code snippet ideal however, whatever the purpose is :)

Comment: The Java way to solve a issue is not necessary the C++ way (as for this case)

Comment: @Jarod42 It's not, but it gives benefits by stating errors at compile time instead of runtime. If there is a way to make the code more succinct and expressive, at the same time saving compile-time checks of function adequate implementation and use, then it would be perfect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214804/discussion-between-andrey-ilyunin-and-jarod42).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide definitions for all functions of your classes. That means even if you only derive classes from `Predicate` and `Producer` you still have to implement the `operator()` in those classes.

If you don't want to do that (i.e. only have the function declaration but no definition), consider making these two classes **abstract** by declaring the `operator()` methods **pure virtual**. Then you cannot instantiate an object directly from these classes but only from *derived* classes that implement the `operator()` method. And that also means you can only pass `Predicate<V>*` in your `HowMuch` constructor.

Comment: Pointer conversion with conjunction of making function both `virtual` and `=0` did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want Predicate to be an abstract class, you need to:

-make the bool operator() method virtual and set it to 0 (in Predicate class):

```
virtual bool operator()(const T& x) const=0;
```

-store a reference to the Predicate in HowMuch:

```
explicit HowMuch(Predicate<V> &p) : predicate{p} {}
Predicate<V> &predicate;
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, @FMeinicke answered just this, and your answer is more explicit in the context of "pure virtual". Placed an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance seems not justified in your case, you might get rid of your base classes:

```
template <typename T>
class LessThan {
public:
    explicit LessThan(const T& v) : val(v) {}
    bool operator()(const T& x) const { return x < val; }

private:
    T val;
};

template <typename Predicate>
class HowMuch {
   public:
    explicit HowMuch(Predicate p) : predicate{p} {}

    template <typename Container>
    int operator()(const Container& c) const {
        int count = 0;
        for (const auto& x : c)
            if (predicate(x)) ++count;
        return count;
    }

private:
    Predicate predicate;
};

int main() {
    const LessThan<int> lf(5);
    const HowMuch<LessThan<int>> hm(lf);
    std::list<int> li {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    std::cout << "How much numbers less than 5 is in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "
            "10}? Answer: "
         << hm(li)
         << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37007339d20561d3)

If you really want base class as interface, you need pure virtual call

```
template <typename T>
class Predicate {
public:
    virtual ~Predicate() = default;
    virtual bool operator()(const T& x) const = 0;
};

template <typename C, typename T>
class Producer {
public:
    virtual ~Producer() = default;
    virtual T operator()(const C& c) const = 0;
};
```

You also need to fix the object slicing you have:

```
template <typename C, typename V>
class HowMuch : public Producer<C, int> {
   public:
    explicit HowMuch(const Predicate<V>& p) : predicate{&p} {}
    int operator()(const C& c) const override {
        int count = 0;
        for (const auto& x : c)
            if ((*predicate)(x)) ++count;
        return count;
    }

private:
    const Predicate<V>* predicate;
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad8a71965861157a)

Comment: How to achieve strong typing if I want to create several others `Predicate` implementations with statically declared, and, thus, evaluated at compile time, overloaded invocation operator if interface inheritance is thrown away? Making the predicate just a type parameter will compile and run program nicely as it seems, thus the result will be kind of undefined if an object \ lambda that was placed as a `Predicate` implementer won't return a value that is supposed to represent a boolean result.

Comment: Concerning the second part of the answer - it's suitable to resolve the stated problem, so upvote is given

Comment: If you give wrong predicate, you will have compile time error. template give strong typing even if it allows [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: Duck typing implies runtime method resolution, doesn't it? How can runtime error be avoided then if a requested method does not exist?

Comment: From what I see there is drawback in scalability (can't easily add different implementations, as they are now ad hoc) and substuitability (can't have a variable typed as `HowMuch<PredicateInterface>` containing value of `HowMuch<SpecificPredicate>`) of this little "solution", but in return it permits to reduce the codebase size. The basic trade-off that unsafe programming offers, or am I wrong?

Comment: Duck typing is done at compile time in C++ (contrary to python).  `HowMuch<LessThan>` is mostly a copy/paste of `HowMuch<Predicate>` with substitution of `Predicate` by `LessTan`.

Comment: If checks are made during compile-time then it's a clear optimization, thanks :)

Comment: `HowMuch<LessThan>` and `HowMuch<GreaterThan>` would indeed be unrelated classes. Interface allows to abstract two classes and then be able to have (runtime) collection of `IPredicate<int>`. (So indeed we can mix them, but it is not necessary).